# Excel time difference between dates jumping with day change

Tags: excel, elapsedtime

I am trying to calculate the time elapsed in a list of dates spanning 3 days.

When the date changes from 10/1/2021 to 10/2/2021 my time difference jumps up +30 days!!!

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I would like for line 454 to read 0:7:22:02.841.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to use the the elapsed time as my X axis.

Here is the link for the sample files:

[SampleData.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yi6IK5HL1Yf0x08hDh6dhZLkWmA-g5kz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104309807588901173788&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[CSV_SampleData.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JM9sSSkIhG62N-5MOHWG_J8PIgc6oirS/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you very much.

[EDIT]: Changed link to Google Drive.

[EDIT2]: Had to move on to something else and never did find a solution for this. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: Looks like a mix-up of US vs non-US dates. Is '1/10/2021' actually 1-Oct-2021 or 10-Jan-2021? Using the key sequence Ctrl-Shift-# will remove any formatting and show you the underlying Excel value (a double-precision number for dates/times).

Comment: My malware tool lights up for your link. Please use a malware free site like DropBox or OneDrive for sharing files. These are free to use.

Comment: If your list of dates spans three days, why then do you expect to see a result for 7 days and change?

Comment: @DS_London  You are correct. Once I use Ctrl+Shft+# it is clear that it jumped from an-10 to Feb-10. Still, how can I get Excel to recognize that what is changing is the day and not the month? Even when I change the format of the original data it still calculates the time difference with that +30 day jump. Thanks.

Comment: @teylyn: Changed the link. Also, the 7 is in the hours location. Thanks.

Comment: Carlos, format NEVER has an impact on calculation. Dates are numbers, formatted to show as DMY or MYD, depending on your convention. How is Excel to know if you want Jan-10 or Oct-1??? You need to fix the data. Garbage in - garbage out, as they say.

Comment: @teylyn. I understand what you mean. Unfortunately I have no control on how this data is logged. However, I imagine this in not some obscure corner case. There must be some solution. Otherwise it would be impossible for Americans to exchange data with the rest of the world!

Comment: This is a situation where you must "groom" your data, with knowledge of the incoming format. It sounds like your locality uses DMY format, but the data is in MDY format (US). My guess is the original source data is strictly text and then converted to an Excel data value (incorrectly) and displayed in your local DMY format. So you'll have to preprocess the data before your formulas will work correctly. Depending on your input format, there are several ways to do that, here's [one](http://projectwoman.com/2011/03/excel-convert-dates-from-mdy-to-dmy.html).

Comment: How is the data arriving in Excel in the first place? That is where the error lies: presumably you’ll have an issue on 13-Oct …

Comment: @DS_London the data is generated by the PC running a 3D printer. I have not control on how the data is written onto a CSV file. I am adding a link on the original post to the CSV file. Thanks.

Comment: @Carlos You might find one of the answers at [How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul) useful.